# numpy filter 2D array with 2D pandas mask

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array I would like to filter values based on a condition.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['C']])
mask = ~pd.isna(data)
filtered_data = data.values[mask.values]
> ['A', 'B', 'C']   // expcted: [['A', 'B'], ['C']
```

I already explored any solutions on SO where you filter using `np.isnan` but that doesn't work when all your data types are not numbers. I have a mix of string and NaN.

How can I get a 2D array where all the NaN values are stripped? I would prefer a vectorized a solution  rather than looping over each dimension in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think list comprehension would be the fastest:

```
vals = data.to_numpy()
filtered_data = [list(v[m]) for v, m in zip(vals, pd.notna(vals))]
```

Alternative pandas based approach with `stack` and `groupby`:

```
filtered_data = data.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list).tolist()
```

Result

```
print(filtered_data)

[['A', 'B'], ['C']]
```